# Kafka connect running very slow and throwing intermittent error

Tags: apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to copy content of one topic test1 to another topic test1_connect

Content is protobuf message.

I have tried kafkacat but looks like it doesnt work for protobuf message.

So i tried replicator(connect-distributed) and below are the configs of the same.

connect-distirbuted.properties

```
bootstrap.server =<bootstrap server>
compression.type=snappy
group.id=...
key.convertor =json....
value.convertor =json...
offset.storage.topic=offsets
config.storage.topic=configs
status.storgae.topic=status

send.buffer.bytes=33554432
offset.flush.interval.ms=1000000

replicator.json

{
    name:replicator, 
    config:{
          <normal config but source and       destination cluster is same. >
    } 
}
```

Though its working but its very slow.

Observation

1. Every feq minutes its doing some auth stuff which we generally see during kafka start.
2. I see lot of error like

   Failed to send record to test1_connect kafkaexception :produxer is closed forcefully.
3. TimeoutException:Adminclient thread is not accepting new calls.
4. Java outofmemoryerror.

Are there any performance optimization which i should be doing.

I never thought kafka connect would require lot of memory. I thought it should be simply copy content of one topic to another very fast as its same cluster.

Comment: Have you found any solution? I am facing similar issue

Comment: I have increased memory, that improved to some extent